# Understanding Intellisense in Vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to nodejs and started using vscode recently but pretty good with Javascript and its wonderful features. I am having some trouble understanding the parameters that the intellisense is showing.

[image]

What exactly does this line mean, this intellisense is so confusing!. Is there some extension that I can install which will give the boiler plate code if I want to use for eg: watch method.

Thanks and please dont down vote, this is a genuine question as to how to make sense of the intellisence.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listener?: (event: string, filename: string) => any`

From left to right:

- `fs.watch` accepts an **optional** argument `listener` (the `?` indicates this)
- `listener` should be a `function` accepting two parameters: `event` and `filename`. (Technically you could write a function that doesn't accept any, but you'd lose information)
- `listener` doesn't need to return anything (`=> any`)

There's more information [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio), including how VS Code actually generates this annotations.

Comment: Is this the standard convention ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: By knowing just this, I should be able to get around any intellisence for any methods. Or is this something I need to learn

Comment: This actually [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) notation. Look it up , even you don't plan to use it, that's what vscode uses to give you intellisense. Its really simple and straightforward.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Is there any extension in VSCode that autocompletes the method parameters?